# Compare the price of grocery

Tags: android, web-apps, ios

Is there any system that helps compare the price of grocery lists among many stores? Ideally, it would have an store and item database that could permit scan the barcode with a smartphone to assemble the list.

It must be available in Canada.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Smoopa](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smoopa.client.android):

- free
- Android and iOS
- barcode scan
- currently compare prices with online retailers such as Amazon, Walmart, Target, Best Buy, and Macy's

[image]

Comment: Note that it is available only in some countries.