# Android app to create and visualise price history database

Tags: android, comparison

I am looking for app that allows easy adding and comparing price entries.

For example I would be able to enter that 500GB SSD disk costs 400PLN or that 2kg bag of onions costs 2 PLN, with two effects

- See whether the price is economical, compared to stored data
- Price is saved for future comparisons

Price entry would be info how much something cost at certain shop and may include things like

- price
- name
- amount (with unit)
- date
- shop
- and potentially more (barcode, category etc)

App would allow adding such entries and comparing them with existing ones.

So it is absolutely necessary for me that

- app works on Android 6
- it is possible to import/export my own data
- it is possible to maintain unit list (so I can add custom unit and delete predefined ones useless for me)
- if app is paid then one can test it without paying (version with adds or with some other limit like database size)
- app is capable of working offline
- app is available in English or Polish or has a very intuitive interface

It would be even better if

- there is available version without adds (may be paid)
- app is open-sourced
- app is actively developed
- it is possible to set currency symbol
- date is autoset to current one
- shop is preset to one from definable list based on location
- app is using price entries sourced from Internet/other users/whatever else, not only ones that I collected
- there is possible to maintain list of synonyms (one product may have several names)

Comment: Note: I already looked through https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/shopping_deals#group_296 https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13629/android-app-to-compare-prices https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28664/iphone-app-for-grocery-shopping-with-inventory-control-and-tracking-of-past-pric https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6821/compare-the-price-of-grocery etc

Answer (score 1):

Hitting every point on your list is going to be tricky, but if I can propose a free alternative, EasyDatabase (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dsiastur.easy_database&hl=en_GB)

The export is limited to CSV, or PDF for reporting, but you should be able to construct everything you want from this, including barcode generation and handling.

The developer is very active too, if you had any specific queries, but it isn't FOSS, and I think the DB is hosted on the android device specifically, so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I would say that [Memento](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.luckydroid.droidbase) might be your best bet!